# How Do I Reproduce this Three-Column Format Within Enumerate?

Tags: enumerate, multicolumn

To be clear, I don't demand that I use enumerate. I just want to reproduce the image. I tried variations of flalign and multicols but couldn't get it to work.

[image]

Comment: You can use a table to reproduce this image. `Tabularry` provides tools to enumerate inside the table.

Comment: `Tabularray` is the correct name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see much scope for an `enumerate` environment here. Instead, I'd create a four-column `tabular` environment, where I'd define the first column to automatically increment a counter and display it as a lowercase-alphabetical "numeral". Oh, and I would right-align rather than left-align these alphabetical-style numerals.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{array}      % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} % left aligned & automatic inline math mode
\newcounter{tabrowcount} % create dedicated counter for row nums
% Column type for an automatically incremented counter. (If you prefer
% left-alignment, change "r" to "l" at end of the def. of the column type.)
\newcolumntype{z}{>{\stepcounter{tabrowcount}\alph{tabrowcount}.}r} 
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % optional: Palatino-clone text and math fonts

\begin{document}
Show that each statement form in column~I is logically 
equivalent to the form next to it in column~II.
\begin{center}
\setcounter{tabrowcount}{0} % (re)initialize the counter
\begin{tabular}{@{} z L L l @{}}
\mc{} % Create an empty cell in first column
  & \mc{\bfseries I} & \mc{\bfseries II} \\[0.5ex]
  & A\Rightarrow(B\Rightarrow C) & (A\wedge B)\Rightarrow C \\
  & A\wedge(B\vee C) & (A\wedge B)\vee(A\wedge C) & Distributive Law \\
  & \dots \\
  & \dots \\
  & \dots \\
  & \dots \\
  & A\Leftrightarrow B & B\Leftrightarrow A & Biconditional commutativity  
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question posted in the comments below this answer: The OP hasn't provided nearly enough information to diagnose fully what may be going on, let alone come up with a solid remedy. I can only surmise that some of the expressions in the two math columns and/or in the final column are sufficiently long so as the make the width of the `tabular` environment exceed `\textwidth`, prompting the `Overfull \hbox` warning.

Since I'm not in a position to conduct a proper diagnosis, I can offer up only a very generic remedy.

- Add the following instructions to the preamble:

  ```
  \usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
  \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % ragged-right version of X col. type
  ```
- Change

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{@{} z L L l @{}}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} z L L Y @{}}
  ```
- Change `\end{tabular}` to `\end{tabularx}`.

If you've guessed that, taken together, these changes allow automatic line breaking in the final column and thereby help prevent the creation of overfull lines, you would be entirely correct.

Comment: As always, your % comments are super helpful for non-wizards like me!

Comment: No `table`, please. This `tabular` has no caption and should be placed exactly below the description text. By the way, it's not the `table` environment that steps the `table` counter, so your `tabrowcounter` doesn't get reset.

Comment: @egreg - Good catch. I think I went the `table` route planning to provide a `\caption` statement that would reset the `tabrownum` counter, but then got distracted by something and forgot the provide the required code. I agree that since the OP provided no indication that the table should float, the use of a `table` environment is probably not called for to begin with.

Comment: Oh my, why/how does using a `\multicolumn` in row 1, column 1, overwrite the `>{\stepcounter}` automatism? And: is this "the" idiomatic way/macro to interrupt such automatic, or is there a dedicated macro for that as well?

Comment: @ojdo - `\multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` is a powerful and, yes, idiomatic method for overriding the default structure of a single cell. The default structure/column type of the (1,1) cell is `z` which, in turn, is based on the `r` column type (with some fancy preface code). The instruction `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` tells LaTeX to use the `c` column type instead of the `z` column type for that cell and to keep that cell empty. You ask if there's a macro for this substitution; how about `\newcommand\ZZZ{\multicolumn{1}{c}{}}`? That said, I don't think one can say that `\ZZZ` is easier than `\mc{}`.

Comment: @Mico The 2nd column of one of the rows has an expression `(A\land B)\lor(\lnot A\land\lnot B)` which is longer than the others and is thereby causing an `Overfull \hbox` warning. What would be your remedy if faced with this warning?

Comment: @Gary - What's in the final, i.e., right-hand column of the row in question?

Comment: @Mico Nothing. It's empty.

Comment: @Gary - Please see the addendum I posted at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Mico "The OP hasn't provided nearly enough information to diagnose fully what may be going on"  What kind of information are you referring to? I merely used the tabular structure you created to attempt to finish the table. I sent you the expression that was too long and told you it was in the "II" column (third column). I told you the final column is empty. If you're asking about the "I" column, it contains only the short expression `A\Leftrightarrow B`, but leaving it blank doesn't cause the warning to go away. Either way, thank you for the addendum.

Comment: @Gary - You've told us, first, that one of the math columns has become wider because one cell in that  column consists of `(A\land B)\lor(\lnot A\land\lnot B)`. Second, the entire `tabular` environment -- and not just the row that contains the wide cell -- has gotten sufficiently wide so as to exceed the width of the text block. You have *not* provided information about how wide the text block is or how wide the other columns are. In short, there's not enough information to fully diagnose the situation. Hence my rather generic attempt at a remedy. Glad to read that it may have helped.

Comment: @Gary - Some of the additional information you provide in the most recent comment, such as the claim that "I told you the final column is empty", is actually very confusing. Doesn't the far-right `l` column (which typesets its material in text mode) contain long-ish phrases such as `Biconditional commutativity`? Shouldn't `A\Leftrightarrow B` be in one of the two math-mode columns (which have type `L`, not `l`)? If `A\Leftrightarrow B` really is in the final column, why doesn't LaTeX throw a warning message (since `\Leftrightarrow` is a math-mode directive)?

Comment: @Mico As the original screenshot shows, some rows have text in the fourth column, while others don't. The row that is causing the overfull \hbox has no text in that column. In my comment, I referenced the "I" column (that's a capital I, i.e., roman numeral one, i.e., the first "L" column), and will henceforth adopt your notation. So `A\Leftrightarrow B` is the sole content in the first "L" column for that particular row. Even if I leave that cell empty, I get the same \hbox warning. It's clearly a problem with the second "L" column's contents being too long, and nothing else.

Comment: @Gary - Your claim that "The row that is causing the overfull \hbox has no text in that column" is beside the point. The widths of `l` and `L` type columns are determined by the widest cells in the respective columns. It doesn't matter if a particular cell in that column is empty, as the column's overall width is determined by the single widest cell -- e.g., `Biconditional commutativity`. The "Overfull `\hbox`" warning is caused by the entire `tabular` environment being too wide, rather than by one cell in one column being too wide. To focus on the width of one particular cell is pointless.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} % left aligned & automatic inline math mode

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}>{\OnlyMainNiceMatrix{\alph{iRow}.}}rLLl@{}}[first-row]
  & \Block[c]{}{\bfseries I} & \Block[c]{}{\bfseries II} \\[0.5ex]
  & A\Rightarrow(B\Rightarrow C) & (A\wedge B)\Rightarrow C \\
  & A\wedge(B\vee C) & (A\wedge B)\vee(A\wedge C) & (Distributive Law) \\
  & \dots \\
  & \dots \\
  & \dots \\
  & \dots \\
  & A\Leftrightarrow B & B\Leftrightarrow A & (Biconditional commutativity)  
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 8):

You can start from here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\newcounter{tabitem}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\stepcounter{tabitem}\makebox[21pt][r]{\alph{tabitem}.\;\,}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[1cm,c]X[l]X[l]X[l]},rows={1cm,m},cell{1}{2,3}={c}}
             & {\Large I} & {\Large II} & \\
\tabitem    & $some math text$&$more math text$& \\
\tabitem    & $even more math$&$ and more$     & (Distributive law)\\
\tabitem    & so so on . . .    & and so om      & (Distributive law)\\              
        \end{tblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I'd also do it with a `tabular`, but with some modifications with respect to other similar answers.

The `exlist` environment is customizable for different number of columns. Display math is used (with a trick) to get the table flush left. The argument is the column specification, with `M` denoting a left aligned math column, so we can spare several `$` characters.

I also define two new symbols `\lto` and `\liff` for the arrows used as binary operation symbols instead of relations.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % to reproduce the image font

\newcommand{\lto}{\mathbin\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\liff}{\mathbin\Leftrightarrow}

\newcounter{exlist}
\renewcommand{\theexlist}{\alph{exlist}}

\newenvironment{exlist}[1]
 {%
  \[ % (ab)use display math
  \hspace{0pt}% to get flush left
  \setcounter{exlist}{0}% reset the counter
  \begin{tabular}{%
    @{}
    >{\refstepcounter{exlist}\theexlist.}l
    #1
    @{}
  }%
 }
 {\end{tabular}\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}\]}
\newcommand{\exlistheader}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{} & #1%
}

\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}l<{$}} % Math column

\begin{document}

Show that each statement form in column~I is logically equivalent
to the form next to it in column~II.
\begin{exlist}{MMl}
\exlistheader{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{I}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{II}}} \\
& A \lto (B \lto C) & (A \land B) \lto C \\
& A \land (B \lor C) & (A \land B) \lor (A \land C) & (Distributive Law) \\
& A \lor (B \land C) & (A \lor B) \land (A \lor C) & (Distributive Law) \\
& (A \land B) \lor \lnot B & A \lor \lnot B \\
& (A \lor B) \land \lnot B & A \land \lnot B \\
& A \lto B & \lnot B \lto \lnot A & (Law of the contrapositive) \\
& A \liff B & B \liff A & (Biconditional commutativity)
\end{exlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution with TeX primitives:

```
\def\lto{\mathbin\Rightarrow}
\def\liff{\mathbin\Leftrightarrow}

Show that each statement form in column~I is logically equivalent
to the form next to it in column~II.
$$
  \vbox{\halign{#\hfil\quad & $#\hfil$\quad & $#\hfil$\quad & #\hfil \cr
       & \hfil\hbox{\bf I} &  \hfil\hbox{\bf II} \cr
    a. & A \lto (B \lto C) & (A \land B) \lto C \cr
    b. & A\land  (B\lor C) & (A\land B)\lor(A\land C) & Distributive Law \cr
    c. & A \lor (B\land C) & (A\lor B) \land (A \lor C) & Distributive Law \cr
    d. & (A\land B) \lor \lnot B & A \lor \lnot B \cr
    e. & (A\lor B) \land \lnot B & A \land \lnot B \cr
    f. & A\lto B & \lnot B \lto \lnot A & Law of the contrapositive \cr
    g. & A \liff B & B \liff A & Biconditional commutativity \cr
  }}
$$
```

Comment: This response really intrigues me. It seems like your answer might be simpler than the LaTeX-focused answers! Is it feasible for a professional mathematician to do document preparation in TeX only? Is it advisable?

Comment: @Gary The math typesetting is about 90 % the same from TeX (or plain TeX) point of view and from LaTeX. You can compare the pure TeX math (without LaTeX) using my document optex-math  http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/optex-math.pdf